# Spring data repository Aggregation

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using Spring data and have a repository with some data about cars.

My interface:

```
public interface CarRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Car, String> {

    public List<Car> findByYear(int year);

    public List<Car> findByYearGreaterThan(int year);

}
```

How can I create a method to use faceted search (I believe they are called aggregations on Elasticsearch) on my repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end using ElasticSearchTemplate it was easy (since it access the same index).